# loop for validating a 5 character long string only

Tags: while-loop

i'm fairly basic to java as i have just started computing A-level at school, i am doing an exercise where i need to get the user to enter a string (can contain any character) that is 5 characters long only... how would i create a while loop to only allow a five character string to be entered or if not a while loop what other method is better, preferably as simple as possible as i'm new to java.

i have tried looking for it online but i cannot find a simple solution, and i have no idea where to properly start. i tried making a while loop for when (sting != 5) but obviously that does not work as the string is not an integer, i am very confused and need help.

Comment: Please add some relevant code showing what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
if(enteredString.length() != 5){
    System.out.println("information entered is not 5 characters long");
}
```

some good source of fibre... :)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html (Tells you everything String Object does.)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html (Teaches you some String manipulation)

Enjoy.